# Citroen C4 Picasso - Whining noise when turning steering wheel

Tags: noise, power-steering, citroen, picasso

When turning the steering wheel on my Citroen C4 Picasso (64 plate), the front end generates a "whining noise". This noise happens regardless of whether the car is moving or not. It happens when the wheel is being turned quickly - by turning it slowly, the whining can be prevented.

The sound is a medium pitched whirring as opposed to a high pitched sqealing sound that might be indicative of a slipping belt.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it a lower tone noise like a whirring or a high pitched screeching sound?

Comment: @DucatiKiller From my limited experience, it's not the high pitched squealing sound that I would normally associate with a belt slipping. It is a bit like a medium frequency whirring.

Comment: I would agree, probably not a belt slipping.

Comment: After doing a bit more research, it looks like your C4 has an electric power steering pump, so I have deleted my answer.  First thing to check as @DucatiKiller says is the fluid level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon the information you've provided I can think of two things that may create the "medium frequency whirring" sound.

**1.  Low Power Steering Fluid**

When your power steering fluid is low the fluid cannot absorb sound and what you hear is the pump possibly going bad as a result.  Sometimes, when the fluid is just low there will be audible component based upon the lack of sound absorption properties that are the fluid's innate properties.

**2.  Power Steering Pump Failure**

As above, the pump can make the sound you describe when going into a failed state.  I'm unsure of the sound source though.

I would defer to @handyhowie chiming in based upon the newer information you have provided or another resource on the site that might be more knowledgeable.

I will say I am sure that the fluid could be low or the pump could be failing.  Rather vanilla, I know....but I know those are at least two possibilities.

Comment: Also a bad rack & pinion can cause the pump to make a low whining noise.

Comment: Post that as a possible answer.  That's good.

Comment: Dunno, I need more data. @OP, any weird sounds (clunks) or vibrations coming from the front suspension?

Comment: Thanks for the info - on this car, there doesn't seem to be any mention of the power steering tank at all in the user's manual. I've had a look under the bonnet and I can see the brake fluid, washer fluid and what appears to be the radiator fluid reservoir (it's got a thermometer symbol on the cap), but can't for the life of me find out where the power steering fluid tank would be!

Comment: Does your engine bay look like this? - https://teon.co/cars/citroen-c4-petrol-1-dot-6/manuals/51b71dfba114603275000252/chapters/weekly-checks/chapter_parts/checking-steering-fluid

Comment: @HandyHowie  I know there is a better answer to this question than the one I've provided....but some of the other items that are possible are things I've never encountered so I don't want to pontificate about them.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Sorry, I should have directed that at the OP, I was trying to help him identify where his power steering reservoir might be.

Comment: @HandyHowie  Oh yes, understood.  I just interrupted your convo with the OP with my thought hoping you would give a better answer than mine.  I think the only reason I have votes on it is because it's the only answer and I know it falls short.

Comment: @DucatiKiller. Everything you have written looks fine to me.